# Program to print and display identity matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, identity

i am having trouble writing a program that prints a matrix, and then I generate the identity matrix. Here is my ccode below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int PrintMatrix(int dim, double matrix[dim][dim]);
int main()

int PrintMatrix(int dim, double matrix[dim][dim]) {
int aa, bb;
for (aa = 0; aa <= dim; aa++) {
    for (bb = 0; bb <= dim; bb++) {
        printf("%lf ", matrix[aa][bb]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

double TestMatrix[7][7] = {
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
};
    PrintMatrix(7, TestMatrix);
return 0;
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a function inside another function? (`PrintMatrix` inside of `main`) You can't do that.

Comment: actually you can ( nonstandard but eg. gcc allows it )

Comment: When I print it out, it does not return the identity. it returns, for example identity of of 3x3:
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

Comment: It still isn't returning the identity for dim = 2 up to 7, any thoughts?

Comment: @tgood `int PrintMatrix(int part_size, int dim, double matrix[dim][dim]);`, `PrintMatrix(3, 7, TestMatrix);`

Comment: @tgood - 1) copy/paste Dilip Kumar's program verbatim, run it, and verify it does what you want.  2) Note how he structured his loops.  Note especially all the open/close braces.  Note the "<" vs. "<=".  Note his indentation.  3) Post back if you have any follow-on questions.  4) Upvote and accept Dilip Kumar's answer.

Comment: To accept an answer, click on the tick mark (check mark in American) under the voting arrowheads by the answer.  Only the person asking the question sees that and can select a selected answer.  You also get a small bonus for accepting an answer.

Comment: As BluePixy hinted, if you lie to your compiler about the size of the input matrix to the function, for example by passing a 7x7 matrix but telling that it has a 3x3 matrix, it gets its revenge by printing different information from what you wanted.  Don't lie to the compiler!  If you want to print identity matrices of sizes 1..7 from a 7x7 matrix, tell the compiler (function) both the actual size of the matrix and the size you want printed.  For an identity matrix, you don't actually need the original matrix — you could synthesize the data.

Comment: For printing the top left square subset of an arbitrarily sized square matrix, you must pass both the size of the data to be printed and the actual size of the matrix. Printing an arbitrary rectangular subset of an arbitrarily sized rectangular matrix requires many more function parameters (7 if I am counting correctly: `void PrintSubMatrix(int row, int col, int width, int height, int x_size, int y_size, double matrix[x_size][y_size]);`), and that's before you specify the file stream to write on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your code won't compile successfully.
2. After `main` there is no opening brace.
3. You are defining function inside `main`, which is an issue.
4. Check for parentheses in whole code.
5. Fixed the loop controls from `<=` to `<`.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int PrintMatrix(int dim, double matrix[dim][dim]);
int main()
{
    double TestMatrix[7][7] = {
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };
    PrintMatrix(7, TestMatrix);
    return 0;
}

int PrintMatrix(int dim, double matrix[dim][dim]) {
    int aa, bb;
    for (aa = 0; aa < dim; aa++) {
        for (bb = 0; bb < dim; bb++) {
            printf("%lf ", matrix[aa][bb]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also point out that you (correctly) fixed the loops in the `PrintMatrix()` function to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for notifying yeah i missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is an appalling non-compiling mess.  One of the comments is:

> It still isn't returning the identity for dim = 2 up to 7; any thoughts?

As [BluePixy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804731/program-to-print-and-display-identity-matrix-in-c/32804807?noredirect=1#comment53447187_32804731), if you lie to your compiler about the size of the input matrix to the function, for example by passing a 7x7 matrix but telling that it has a 3x3 matrix, it gets its revenge by printing different information from what you wanted. Don't lie to the compiler!

If you want to print identity matrices of sizes 1..7 from a 7x7 matrix, tell the compiler (function) both the actual size of the matrix and the size you want printed. For an identity matrix, you don't actually need the original matrix — you could synthesize the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void printIdentityMatrix(int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%4.1f", (i == j) ? 1.0 : 0.0);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        printIdentityMatrix(i);
    return 0;
}
```

For printing the top left square subset of an arbitrarily sized square matrix, you must pass both the size of the data to be printed and the actual size of the matrix.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void PrintMatrix(int size, int dim, double matrix[dim][dim])
{
    assert(size <= dim);
    for (int aa = 0; aa < size; aa++)
    {
        for (int bb = 0; bb < size; bb++)
            printf("%lf ", matrix[aa][bb]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    double TestMatrix[7][7] =
    {
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        PrintMatrix(i, 7, TestMatrix);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Printing an arbitrary rectangular submatrix of an arbitrarily sized rectangular matrix requires many more function parameters (7 if I am counting correctly:

```
void PrintSubMatrix(int x_off, int y_off, int x_len, int y_len, int x_size, int y_size,
                    double matrix[x_size][y_size]);
```

and that's before you specify the file stream to write on.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void PrintSubMatrix(int x_off, int y_off, int x_len, int y_len, int x_size, int y_size,
                        double matrix[x_size][y_size])
{
    assert(x_off >= 0 && x_off < x_size && x_off + x_len <= x_size);
    assert(y_off >= 0 && y_off < y_size && y_off + y_len <= y_size);
    printf("SubMatrix size %dx%d at (%d,%d) in M[%d][%d]\n",
           x_len, y_len, x_off, y_off, x_size, y_size);
    for (int x = x_off; x < x_off + x_len; x++)
    {
        for (int y = y_off; y < y_off + y_len; y++)
            printf("%4.1f ", matrix[x][y]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    double TestMatrix[7][9] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 },
        { 2, 1, 9, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 3, 0, 8, 7, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 4, 0, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 6, 0, 1, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 7, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
    };

    PrintSubMatrix(0, 0, 7, 9, 7, 9, TestMatrix);

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++)
            PrintSubMatrix(i, j, 3 + j - i, i + j, 7, 9, TestMatrix);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
SubMatrix size 7x9 at (0,0) in M[7][9]
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  3.0 
 2.0  1.0  9.0  8.0  4.0  6.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 
 3.0  0.0  8.0  7.0  5.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 
 4.0  0.0  5.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0 
 5.0  0.0  1.0  4.0  7.0  9.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 
 6.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  8.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 
 7.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  9.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0 

SubMatrix size 4x3 at (1,2) in M[7][9]
 9.0  8.0  4.0 
 8.0  7.0  5.0 
 5.0  6.0  6.0 
 1.0  4.0  7.0 

SubMatrix size 5x4 at (1,3) in M[7][9]
 8.0  4.0  6.0  0.0 
 7.0  5.0  5.0  0.0 
 6.0  6.0  8.0  4.0 
 4.0  7.0  9.0  0.0 
 0.0  8.0  1.0  0.0 

SubMatrix size 3x4 at (2,2) in M[7][9]
 8.0  7.0  5.0  5.0 
 5.0  6.0  6.0  8.0 
 1.0  4.0  7.0  9.0 

SubMatrix size 4x5 at (2,3) in M[7][9]
 7.0  5.0  5.0  0.0  0.0 
 6.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0 
 4.0  7.0  9.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  8.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 

SubMatrix size 2x5 at (3,2) in M[7][9]
 5.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  4.0 
 1.0  4.0  7.0  9.0  0.0 

SubMatrix size 3x6 at (3,3) in M[7][9]
 6.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0 
 4.0  7.0  9.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 
 0.0  8.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

It would be better if the code was fixed not to print a blank at the end of each line; that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thankyou for your input Jonathan, no need to be so mean at the start though :( haha, but thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but non-compiling code where the question is not about why it isn't compiling is appalling, and messy.  If the code was compilable but simply not working, there'd be no equivalent comment.